# In C# are the `using` directives of the base class inherited by the child class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, namespaces, using

Let's say we have a base class `Rectangle` and a derived class `Square`:

```
namespace Shapes {
    using System.Foo;

    public class Rectangle {
        public Rectangle(int l, int w){}
    }
}

namespace Shapes {
   public class Square : Rectangle

   public Square(int l, int w){}
}
```

Does the `Square` class have to explicitly say that it is using `System.Foo`?  I'm getting erratic results.  In one project the `using` directives seem to be inherited and in a web application they aren't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`using` statements, in this context, don't compile to code -- they are helpers to make your code read cleaner for others.  As a result, they are not "inherited".

So, to answer your question, your `Square` class needs to reference `System.Foo` - either with a `using` statement, or by using a fully qualified class name.

Comment: Thanks for a clear and concise answer to the question I asked, David.

Answer (score 10):

A `using` statement will only propagate to the next set of closing braces (`}`) from the level it was declared on within the same the file.

```
//From File1.cs
using System.Baz;
namespace Example
{
    using System.Foo;
    //The using statement for Foo and Baz will be in effect here.

    partial class Bar
    {
        //The using statement for Foo and Baz will be in effect here.
    }
}

namespace Example
{
    //The using statement for Baz will be in effect here but Foo will not.

    partial class Bar
    {
        //The using statement for Baz will be in effect here but Foo will not.
    }
}
```

```
//From File2.cs
namespace Example
{
    //The using statement for Foo and Baz will NOT be in effect here.
    partial class Bar
    {
        //The using statement for Foo and Baz will NOT be in effect here.
    }
}
```

Comment: My question was whether the imports became part of the base class. I'm not sure what `propagate` means in the context of class inheritance.

Comment: [Propagate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/propagate): "*to pass along to offspring*". A using statement in a base class will not propagate (be passed along to offspring) child classes.

Comment: Thanks for following up. You said "propagate to the next set of closing braces" and they are not "offspring", so "propagate" is being used to mean more than one thing.

Comment: @Tim [using directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) do not become part of the class, they are part of the code file itself. The compiler (msbuild.exe), and visual studio intellisense use them to resolve type namespaces when compiling your code files.

Answer (score 2):

`using` directives are only shared if the classes are in the same file and they are not nested in the classes themselves like in your example.

For instance:

```
using System.Foo;
namespace N
{
    class A {}
    class B {}
}
```

If this is all in one file, `A` and `B` can both use `Foo`.

Comment: I think "shouldn't" is an overly-strong statement. There are a few corner cases where there's a difference, but it's *mostly* a matter of preference. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/06/25/inside-or-outside.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the article. I have removed my claim.

Answer (score 2):

I think everyone is missing the point when it comes to using directives. They really have nothing to do with the *class* at all. [**using** directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) in a code file (.cs, .vb, etc...) are not part of the classes defined within the file. They are used by the compiler to resolve namespaces when compiling.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Foo;

namespace  Shapes {...
```

Importing should always be top most and not within a namespace. This will allow the entire structure of the class to rely on that import when needed.

Comment: Not clear how their being after the namespace declaration makes the imports not accessible to the `class` in its entirey.